# OpenTextFile gives error Automation server can't create Object

Tags: javascript, filesystems

I created this method to create a text file as log for a page that has different buttons that call functions with parameters from different textfields:

```
function WriteToFile(data) {
    var currentdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = "Time: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var a = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\logs\\log.txt", 8);
    a.WriteLine(datetime);
    a.WriteLine(data + "\n");
    a.Close();
 }
```

And it works perfectly fine when I'm using the C: drive. Unfonrtunately, this is to be used in production in a Z: drive so other people can use the page as well. When I copy it to the Z: drive and change this line:

```
var a = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\logs\\log.txt", 8);
```

to the following:

```
var a = fso.OpenTextFile("Z:\\logs\\log.txt", 8);
```

it gives me an error saying:

> Automation server can't create object

I am using IE8. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried writing it to the UNC path instead of the network drive?

Comment: @Westie I'm kinda new to this, what do you mean with the UNC path? Like `\\logs\log.txt` ?

Comment: For instance, `\\myservername\sharename$\path`.  {edit} Using the appropriate slashes etc!

Comment: Hmmm.  On further reading, it's seems a bit of a mine field.  What browser are you using?

Comment: @Westie yeah, I tried with no luck. I am using IE8

Comment: I did find [this link](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_%3a_Issues_%3a_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work), but it's from 2009 and covers Firefox.  The link suggests using `file://///servername/share/file.ext`.

Comment: @Westie I tried that and I confirmed the path using Windows Explorer and I can get to the file, but keep getting same error in IE8 :/

Comment: @Westie maybe there is another way of doing this? Through PHP maybe?

Comment: PHP is server side.  Could it be an issue with privileges on your shared folder?

Comment: @Westie that's what I thought too, but I gave acces to Everybody to access, read, and write in the folder

Comment: Did you try `\\\\servername\\sharename\\logs\\log.txt`, Randomizertech?

Comment: @Westie yeah I tried that too :( nothing seems to work. I'm not even sure this is doable using JS anymore

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure then.  The only examples I've seen for this have been based on local drives...